# Artificial Neural Network: Calculate weights?

Tags: c#, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I programmed a Artificial Neural Network and it works for simple tasks, but if I try more complex tasks [in my case detection of handwriting with 28x28px image] the weights do random stuff [irregular increase and decrease with very high jumps: for example, an output neuron is 1 and after the next training  0.1 and after a overnext training it is 0.9].
My ANN calulates values from 0 - 1.

**The way I calulate:**

```
float value = 0;
foreach (Connection c in connections)
{
    value += c.GetValue();
}
value = MathA.Sigmoid(value);
this.value = value;
```

**The way i calculate new weights now:**

```
float newWeight = currentWeight * lernRate * entrieNeuronValue * (answer - expectedAnswer);
```

**Do anyone know a better way to calulate the weights?**

Comment: We need far more information about your project. What kind of data is this. What means "random stuff". How do you create the netweork?

Comment: Ok, I changed it now.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is this part `(answer - expectedAnswer)`.
Depending on the value of `answer` the result of `(answer - expectedAnswer)` can be positiv or negativ. A negativ result of this calculation results in a negativ weight. A negativ weight brings chaos to your calculation of the next answer and/or weight. 
Weights have to be between 0 and 1.